# Can I use python to toggle windows 10 notifications?

Tags: python, windows, notifications, windows-10, toast

I want to use python to toggle permissions for facebook messenger app to push notifications to my windows 10 laptop. How would I go about doing this? Is this even possible to do in python?

[This is the menu I am trying to edit (Notifications and actions page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixFKx.png)

Comment: What you are looking for is called an API. If FB messenger has an API with Python support, yes, you can toggle the settings.

Comment: I am not intending to use this just for messenger but other apps such as cortana. This is a windows setting rather than a FB setting @theGtknerd

Comment: The principle is still the same. You need to connect to the API (if it exists).